# How to determine first week day in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, locale, nscalendar

I am using Tapku's calendar in my application and I want to determine if the week should start on a Sunday or a Monday depending on the user's settings. I am calling firstWeekday, but for some reason it returns 1 (Sunday) on a device where the built-in calendar starts the weeks on Mondays (and hence it should return 2):

```
NSCalendar* cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[cal firstWeekday];
```

Any suggestions as to what I might be missing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out this is the correct way of doing it:

```
[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] firstWeekday]
```

Answer (score -7):

How to change the default start day of the week in the iPhone and iPad calendar
Launch the Settings app on your iPhone or iPad.
Scroll down and tap on Mail, Contacts, Calendars.
Under the Calendars section, tap on Start Week On.
Here you can change the day of the week your calendar starts on.

Comment: The question is asking about finding it programmatically, not by manual interaction with the Settings app.